# Algorithm to create non-overlapping POI icons on a map

Tags: javascript, algorithm, gis, data-visualization

I want to create various-sized icons on a map representing Points of Interest (POIs). When there is ample space, larger icons should be used. In more crowded areas, smaller icons are used.

For example:
[image]

This is from [Sygic Travel](https://travel.sygic.com/). The density is maintained at various zoom levels. I assume there is some kind of weighting given to prominent POIs to make them appear bigger at various zoom levels.

What I've explored so far includes:

- Binning by grid poisition. This method divides the map into grid squares and counts how many POIs occur on each square. If there's only one POI on a square it can appear as the largest icon. If two or more appear they should be smaller. This method uses the center of POIs so when two POIs occur on adjoining corners they still overlap.
- Spreading icons apart. This method simply pushes POIs away from each other when they are closer than a certain threshold. The problem is they can be pushed into other POIs that then overlap. It is also less accurate because the POI positions on the map are not preserved.

Now I'm thinking about exploring some kind of collision detection like those in physics engines. It would prevent overlap but I'm not sure how it could achieve the requirement of various-sized icons. Another technique might be multi-pass binning with detection of grid space overlap.

Is there an algorithm I'm missing here? Or are there any existing solutions to this problem that I can refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is quite simple:

The map area is defined by some boundary usually using latitude and longitude degrees (for example `south:51.482238, west: -0.18462181, north: 51.529571733, east: -0.058450698`) Also the points you want to draw have some latitude and longitude coordinates, which are within the boundary.

You can think of map as pixel canvas for example 1200x800 pixels (the size is usually defined by size of a map in browser)

Choose one corner of the map as starting coordinate [0,0] (for example [south, west]) and transform latitude, longitude coordinates of points to canvas pixels coordinates.

Then we just order points by some priority and put them one by one on the map. We know size of the marker we want to draw and also markers that have already been drawn, so on the pixel canvas it easy to detect possible collision. The detected collision means than place was taken by point with higher priority. If the point does not fit on map as huge marker, we try to place it as smaller one and so on...

Comment: How do you detect the collisions? It sounds like you place the highest priority points first as large icons and then make them smaller or disappear entirely depending on what space is left. Do you just calculate nearest neighbor distances and if it's above a threshold display an icon?

Comment: We know which markers (position and radius + some margin) are already on canvas and we simply check collision of all of them with new candidate.
Collision detection is done using simple planar geometry (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection).

The output of this algorithm are categories of points. Something like:
{huge: [point, point, point], medium: [point, point, point, ...] }

This is just basic idea. You can then play around with different margins between different sizes or disallow huge markers for some less important places and so on.